# Shortest Palindrome

Tags: java

I've written the code where there is a `String` (initially not palindrome!) and my method has to convert it to palindrome word. For example:

```
Given "aacecaaa", return "aaacecaaa".

Given "abcd", return "dcbabcd".
```

When I try `"abcd"` it just returns me `"dabcd"` despite the fact I also have a helper method `private static boolean check(String myString)` which checks if it has become a palindrome word. 
I've tried to debug the code and the problem is in the method `private static boolean check(String myString)` it does not even enter the loop at all! Could smb please help me out with this problem?

```
public class ConverToPalindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String myString = "abcd";
        String convert = shortestPalindrome(myString);
        System.out.println(convert);
    }

    public static String shortestPalindrome(String myString){
        String finalResult = "";
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = myString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            temp += myString.substring(i) + "" + myString;
            if(check(temp) == true){
                finalResult = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
        return finalResult;
    }

    private static boolean check(String myString){
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = myString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            temp += myString.charAt(i);
        }
        if(temp.equals(myString)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what do you mean with "shortest"? That `aaab` shouldn't be returned as `baaaaab` (append reversted word, without first letter), but rather as `baaab`?

Comment: @Tom, yes, the result should be `baaab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
temp += myString.substring(i) + "" + myString;
```

To

```
temp = new StringBuffer(myString.substring(i)).reverse() + "" + myString;
```

You could also build a temporary string (character by character) in reverse order and combine that with your original string until a palindrome is formed.

```
public static String shortestPalindrome(String myString) {
    String finalResult = "";
    String temp = "";
    String rev = "";
    for (int i = myString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rev += myString.charAt(i);
        temp = rev + myString;
        if (check(temp) == true) {
            finalResult = temp;
            break;
        }
    }
    return finalResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Shar1er80, for pointing out the mistake. I've found my other mistake redid the code and it's working perfectly. (I ran some other loops). But I'll accept your answer!

Comment: @John, If this answer didn't fix the problem, you shouldn't accept it.  Accepting an answer indicates to everyone else who has a similar problem that this is the solution.  It's not about being kind to someone who took the time to help you; it's about being honest with the thousands of others who use Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidWallace This does fix the issue.  John indicates that he redid his code to ALSO get his expected results.

Comment: @DavidWallace, I tried the code that Shar1er80 posted and it gave the same results. It also saved more than several lines of the code than the way I did))